# How to display image in appwidget listview without reload it using Picasso android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget-list

Hi I have thumbnail in my appwidget listview item using Picasso. But it shows as loading when scrolling the listview. I have used the below code for image loading inside RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) method,

```
try {
                Bitmap b = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get();
                remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.feed_image, b);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Is there any way to store it in cache and avoid reloading? Please suggest me an idea.

Comment: Here,
No need to set bitmap at imageview.You can directly load URL using Picasso or Glide.

Comment: @ViramP Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @Sangeetha

Answer (score -1):

Try loading the image directly into your view. Try this:

```
String url= "your img url here";
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(remoteView);
```

This will automatically cache the image and scrolling will not make additional network requests, it will just check if it is already in the cache.

Find more info for this here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Comment: this will work for normal views. I'm using widget listview where i can able to access the views like this  remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.feed_image, b); so i could not use remoview like you specified that is my main problem.